# Firebase data not loading for flutter charts

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, charts

Im new new to flutter charts , as shown in the code snippet below while creating the series(List>) object using datum variable(List) it doesnt show any error but when i create the same series using data variable c (List) which is loaded from firebase it throws the following error ,what should i do to solve this error

```
I/flutter (28785): The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (28785): _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#84465):
I/flutter (28785): type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Support>'
```

code

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection("sports")
          .document("footballl")
          .collection("most_goals")
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return LinearProgressIndicator();
        } else {
          var c =snapshot.data.documents.map((documentsnap) => Support.frommap(documentsnap.data)).toList();          
          print(c);
          var datum = [
            Support("chandru",50),
            Support("eazy",100)
          ];
          print(datum);
          var series = List<charts.Series<Support, String>>();

          series.add(
            charts.Series(
              domainFn: (Support s,_)=>s.domain,
              measureFn: (Support s,_)=>s.measure,
              id: "data",
              data: c
            ));

          print(series);
          return chart(context,series);
        }
      },
    );
```

Comment: Try giving `map` a generic type: `...documents.map<Support>((documentsnap)...`

Comment: What error now, and from which line?